# SQL Left join with duplicate records but different value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following are two tables and required Output.

[image]

For easy, following is the table code.

```
CREATE TABLE #A(CustNo varchar(100), TranID varchar (100), ChkID float)
insert into #A values

('A','A123',200),
('A','A123',100),
('B','B36',200)

CREATE TABLE #B(VCustNo varchar(100), VTransID varchar (100), VCode varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #B VALUES
('A','A123','NN1'),
('A','A123','PP2'),
('A','A123','QQ3')
```

---

and I tried with following query which gives me wrong output.

```
SELECT A.CustNo, A.TranID,A.ChkID, B1.VCustNo, B1.VTransID, B1.VCode
FROM #A A
LEFT JOIN (select VCustNo, min(VTransID) as VTransID, min(VCode) as VCode  from #b group by VCustNo) B1
    ON A.CustNo = B1.VCustNo and a.TranID = B1.VTransID
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need/expect this output, and what is the join logic behind it?

Comment: with my actual database, i have two different tables managed by two different entities. I need to join them with best matching possibilities. VCode needs to be mapped smartly against TbleB,  (currently user is doing manuall matching for now with 1000s of records)  Do not have control over TableB as it is coming from totally different entity

Comment: you said *"I need to join them with best matching possibilities. VCode needs to be mapped smartly against TbleB, (currently user is doing manuall matching for now with 1000s of records)"* - you didn't tell us what a "best match" is, what you mean by "smartly" or what logic the user is doing right now in his "manuall" matching, so we can't really turn the process into code. If the user is applying some external intelligence or deductive reasoning to his process then it may never/improbably be possible to match these things up in code

Answer (score 1):

use full outer join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df2bd8e257def8dce2e822024cae61cb)**

```
select A.CustNo, A.TranID,A.ChkID, B1.VCustNo, B1.VTransID, B1.VCode from
(
SELECT A.CustNo, A.TranID,A.ChkID,row_number() over(partition by custno order by chkid desc) as rn1
FROM #A A
)A
full outer join
(
select B1.VCustNo, B1.VTransID, B1.VCode,row_number() over(partition by VCustNo order by VCode) as rn2
from #B B1
)B1 ON A.CustNo = B1.VCustNo and a.TranID = B1.VTransID 
    and rn1=rn2
```

OUTPUT:

```
CustNo  TranID  ChkID   VCustNo VTransID    VCode
A       A123    200      A       A123       NN1
A       A123    100      A       A123       PP2
                         A       A123       QQ3
B       B36     200
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to create an articifial join between tables based on order of rows. This won't work out well because rows don't have an order, but you can have a try at it with something like:

```
SELECT A.CustNo, A.TranID,A.ChkID, B.VCustNo, B.VTransID, B.VCode
FROM 
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY ChkId DESC) as fakeid FROM #A) A
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VCustNo ORDER BY VCode ASC) as Vfakeid FROM #B) B
  ON 
    A.CustNo = B.VCustNo and
    a.TranID = B1.VTransID and
    a.FakeID = B.VFakeID
```

It looks like A.ChkId is descending order and b.VCode is ascending order, so if we assign an incrementing number in these orders, to each of the datasets then we can join on it:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #A(CustNo varchar(100), TranID varchar (100), ChkID float)
> insert into #A values
>
> ('A','A123',200),
> ('A','A123',100),
> ('B','B36',200)
>
> CREATE TABLE #B(VCustNo varchar(100), VTransID varchar (100), VCode varchar(100))
> INSERT INTO #B VALUES
> ('A','A123','NN1'),
> ('A','A123','PP2'),
> ('A','A123','QQ3') 
>
> SELECT A.CustNo, A.TranID,A.ChkID, B.VCustNo, B.VTransID, B.VCode
>     FROM 
>       (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY ChkId DESC) as fakeid FROM #A) A
>       FULL OUTER JOIN
>       (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VCustNo ORDER BY VCode ASC) as Vfakeid FROM #B) B
>       ON A.CustNo = B.VCustNo and and a.TranID = B1.VTransID and a.FakeID = B.VFakeID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CustNo | TranID | ChkID | VCustNo | VTransID | VCode
> :----- | :----- | ----: | :------ | :------- | :----
> A      | A123   |   200 | A       | A123     | NN1  
> A      | A123   |   100 | A       | A123     | PP2  
> null   | null   |  null | A       | A123     | QQ3  
> B      | B36    |   200 | null    | null     | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0469e193d3f83dcd013a18a335aa5b5)*

I say it wont work out well because as soon as the "chkid descending, vcode axcending" rule is no longer true you wont get what you want, but there isnt any more data available to join on. I'd recommend you add correct relational data rather than relying on a shifting row pattern - any data inserted to either of these tables can break this relationship at any time (if you add chkid 150 then chkid 100 will no longer relate to vcode pp2)

Comment: in sample it seems in particular order, but actual data would surely not be by any order. Still your solution would work?

Comment: One issue, In TableA, edit secord record from (A123) to (Z11), still it will match with Vcode(pp2), in real it should only match if CustNo=VcustNo AND TransID=VtransID, then only match.  (A)(Z11) should not go with (A)(A123)

Comment: Issue corrected, thanks. Regarding your question "in sample it seems in particular order, but actual data would surely not be by any order" - yep, that's exactly why I caution against this method. Data in DB tables is not related to data in another table "by the order it randomly happens to come out as". I strongly urge you to add more columns to your table to clearly define how your want table A to relate to table B. At the moment, all you've given us to go on is the order, which for reasons explained, isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` and full outer join

```
select a.*,b.* from

(
select *,row_number() over(order by CustNo) rn1 from #A
) a
full outer join
(
select *,row_number() over(order by VCustNo) rn2 from #B
) b on a.CustNo=b.VCustNo and a.TranID=b.VTransID and a.rn1=b.rn2
```